# How to Convert number to string using query builder in entity framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following issue. I retrieve a business from the database with a specified value. The field `businessno` is type of integer. Hereafter is the code

```
ObjectQuery<BUSINESS> q_business =
                     _context.BUSINESS.Include("CUSTOMSOFFICE").Where(
                     "it.BUSINESSNO=" + int.Parse(pv_businessno)).Where(
                     string.Format("(it.BUSINESSSTART >= DATETIME'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}') 
                     and (it.BUSINESSSTART <= DATETIME'{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}')",
                     pv_sdate, pv_edate));
```

Nevertheless users need to give a value and retrieve data from the database of `businessno` like that value.

I search the internet and finally rewrite the code as follow. This code retrieves no records unless the full value of the `businessno` is provided.

```
ObjectQuery<BUSINESS> q_business = 
                      _context.BUSINESS.Where(
                      "CAST(it.BUSINESSNO as System.String) like @abc", new ObjectParameter("abc", busno)).Where(
                      string.Format("(it.BUSINESSSTART >= DATETIME'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}') 
                      and (it.BUSINESSSTART <= DATETIME'{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}')",
                      pv_sdate, pv_edate));
```

My problem is how to convert the number to string.

Comment: Why can't you check `businessno` before making a db query?

Comment: It looks like you are building up a sql string here.  If that is the case then to have a SQL like match on part of the word you need to surround it with % characters.  E.g. WHERE name LIKE '%test%'

Comment: oops. I will rewrite the code and comeback

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Sometimes the most obvious things are not so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127.aspx) method to convert integer to string on server side.

```
ObjectQuery<BUSINESS> q_business = 
      from b in _context.BUSINESS
      where SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)b.BUSINESSNO).Contains(busno) &&
            b.BUSINESSSTART >= pv_sdate &&
            b.BUSINESSSTART <= pv_edate
      select b;
```

Comment: Hi lazyberezovsky. i will try this solution also. Thanks